# Correct IP address to access web application in apache docker container

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, docker-network

I have an easy apache docker setup defined in a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
    apache: 
        image: php:7.4-apache
        command: /bin/bash -c "/var/www/html/startup.sh && exec 'apache2-foreground'"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - /c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts:/tmp/hostsfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

From the `startup.sh` script I want to modify the `hosts` file from the host OS through the volume. Here I want to dynamically add an entry to resolve the hostname `test.local` to the ip address of the docker web application like so:

```
<ip-address> test.local
```

This way I should be able to open the application with the specified hostname `http://test.local` in my local browser.

---

Before writing the `startup.sh` script I wanted to try to manually open the application at `http://172.19.0.2` via the containers IP address I got from

```
docker inspect apache_test
```

But the page won't open: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Shouldn't I be able to access the application from that IP? What am I missing? Do I use the wrong IP address?

*BTW*: I am using Docker Desktop for Windows with the Hyper-V backend

**Edit**: I am able to access the application via `http://localhost` but since I want to add a new entry to the `hosts` file this is not the solution.

Comment: This is Docker's interface's IP address. You should use your server's own IP address.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to access the container via `localhost` as well.

Comment: @Adil about `localhost`: see my edit... With "your server's own IP address" you mean the private IP address of the host that runs Docker Desktop? I've tried opening it with that too (`http://192.168.178.101/`) without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [in newer versions of Docker Desktop for Windows](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221#issuecomment-577371744) you [can't access (ping) your linux containers by IP](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers).

Now there is some [really dirty workaround](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5538#issuecomment-578227204) for this that involves changing a `.ps1` file of your Docker installation to get back the `DockerNAT` interface on windows. After that you need to add a new route in your windows routing table as [described here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221#issuecomment-265337342):

```
route /P add <container-ip> MASK 255.255.0.0 <ip-found-in-docker-desktop-settings>
```

Then you might be able to ping your docker container from the windows host. I didn't test it though...

---

I found a solution to my original issue (resolution of `test.local` to container IP via `hosts` file) while reading one of the threads linked above [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5538#issuecomment-611126380)

That involves setting a free loopback IP in the `127.0.0.0/8` IP range in your `ports` section of the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
ports:
    - "127.55.0.1:80:80"
```

After that you add the following to your `hosts` file:

```
127.55.0.1 test.local
```

And you can open your application at `http://test.local`

To do that for other dockerized applications too just choose another free loopback address.